# firefox cache input properties, why?

Tags: firefox, caching

How can i prevent input caching on web page side? Firefox cache the disabled property and buttons not work after reload. Why he doing this? it's madness!

autocomplete="off" - not work.

Cache-Control: no-store - will denied all page cache, but i need to denied only input cache.

Comment: `autocomplete="off" ` should work, can we see your markup

Comment: Oh, sorry `autocomplete="off"` is work well. I missed something.